# Finding corresponding value in <select> tag and displaying it

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I want to achieve it is when someone select any option from the column 1 dropdown list, it should search for corresponding option in 2nd column and display its value in the 3rd column.

For example, suppose someone selected value 3 from the column 1 dropdown list, the corresponding value to be displayed in column 3 would be 30.

I don't know how to achieve this - can someone guide me a bit?  Here's what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("tbody tr td:nth-of-type(1)").on('change blur input', function() {

    });
});
```

If you'd like, here's my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NPnGX/).

Comment: You need to make your question clearer.  A link to a JSFiddle should be supplementary, not required reading to understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("tbody tr td:nth-of-type(1) select").on("change", function () {
        var thistext = $(this).find(":selected").text().toLowerCase();
        var nexttext = $(this).closest("td").next().find("option[value='" + thistext + "']").text();
        $(this).closest("td").siblings().eq(1).text(nexttext);
    });
});
```

First, you need to put the handler on the `<select>` element, not the `<td>`.

Then, to find the corresponding option in the second menu, I find the one whose value is equal to the lowercase text in the selected option. Then I take its text and put it in the third column.

If that's not what you wanted, maybe you can clarify in the question about what you mean by corresponding options.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NPnGX/14/)

Comment: thank you a lot. just need one advice. should i use nth-of-type() or i should manage everything using eq(). which selector is preferred

Comment: I don't know which is preferred, it probably doesn't make too much difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the index of the selected item in a `select` via `selectedIndex`. Assuming `this` is the `select`, you can have this code:

```
var index = this.selectedIndex;
```

You can then use jQuery's `.eq()` to find the right `option` in the other `select` elements and grab the text using `text()`

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NPnGX/15/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("tbody tr td:nth-of-type(1)").on('change', 'select',function (e) {
        var index = this.selectedIndex;
        var parentTd = $(this).closest('td');
        var nextTd = parentTd.next();
        var text = nextTd.find('select > option').eq(index-1).prop('selected','selected').text();
        nextTd.next().text(text);
    });
});
```